# How to access PSSE working case variables by Python a code

Tags: python-2.7, csv, psse

I am a transmission planning engineer and trying to automate the execution of PSSE 100 times or more at one go through a Python code. I already runs, change loads, reruns psse and write bus based summary report to *.csv file. What I really want to do is select the first active power load variable of a PSSE case and increase it by 1 MW. Then run psse, write results to a csv file. Change the selected load back to its original value and move on to the next active load to do the same again and again until I have done same for all load busses.

This will help me to calculate transmission loss factors for entire network with one go.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@dsmtlk, if you're experienced in Python, you can readily find the information you need in the PSSE API Manual located in your PSSE program folder (mine is in C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE33\DOCS).  The API routines for getting bus data are in section 8.6.  The routine for changing bus data—viz., `psspy.load_data_4()`—is in section 2.21.

If you're new to Python, here are a couple links I found helpful when I first started:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/

Comment: Hi kFof, Thanks for your reply. I have figured it out couple of days after posting the question. Further couple of weeks into it, I managed to do all I need with Python. Now I am running dynamics through Python codes and it saves me hours by not doing prerequisites before running dynamics. Once again, thanks for your contribution and I appreciate it.